# Normals all over the place

Tags: normals

[image]

Something happened to my normals and they're all over the place. I'm guessing it's because of my genius idea of separating the roof from the rest of the mesh (thought I'd have to worry less about the NGONs), but I don't exactly know how to connect it back. How am I supposed to fix it? Re-calculating everything outside doesn't seem to help and especially the left wall (yellow) doens't even match it's bottom partner if I flip it.

Comment: First set the color space to non color data

Comment: Well look at that! Thank you! Does the same help with height maps? I'm sorry I guess I jumped a bit too far with my blending. But I needed a house(s) and all seemed to go quite well until the texturing process.

Comment: Any texture that is meant for data, not color (like a height map) should generally be set to Non Color Data. That tells blender not to gamma correct the map

Comment: Thanks again. I definitely learned something today.